# Femtosecond laser: Why FROG technique has 3 frequency-doubled outputs?

Tags: laser

[image: Illustration of the FROG principle]

If the phase matching condition is perfectly satisfied and the two lines of pulse arrived at the crystal with the same phase, then according to the superposition principle, the composite result should only be the central pulse with frequency 2w. Why there still exist 2 other frequency-doubled pulse at the two original directions? Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with FROG, but aren't the other beams simply double frequency generation from two photons in a single beam, while the middle output takes one photon from each beam?

Comment: This is very true! In experiments, it is observed that the intensity of the two along the original directions are stronger than the middle one. I wonder if there exist the probabilities for either of the case. Thank you!

Comment: related: collinear autocorrelation vs. noncollinear/background-free autocorrelation. The same holds for SH-FROG (which is just a spectrally-resolved autocorrelation). The noncollinear case just helps you to separate the constant terms and filter them by an aperture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple picture,  you are looking at a $\chi^{(2)}$ process which involves the square of the electric field of both beam 1 and 2. So the contributions to the measured sum frequency generation are roughly given by:

$$(\mathbf{E}_1(t)+\mathbf{E}_2(t))^2=\vert E_1(t)\vert^2+\vert E_1(2)\vert^2 + 2 \mathbf{E}_1(t)\cdot \mathbf{E}_2(t)$$

I'm leaving out details about the dielectric function of the material which changes the direction of the E-fields, but you can add those in later.

In any case, there are three contributions. The first is SFG of pulse 1 with itself (i.e your top beam), the second is SFG of the second pulse with itself (bottom beam), and the final is from pulse 1 and pulse 2 together (middle beam). Notice that at the very best case the third term with be equal to the sum of the other two, and in the worst case it is zero. This is why generally the middle beam in your diagram is weaker than the other two beams which don't require sensitive phase matching conditions.